# Google Directory API Customer Update Scope

Tags: oauth, google-apps

I am trying to update a primary email domain for a google apps account. And I can't seem to figure out the scope needed.

I keep receiving a 403 error when I make a request

Here is what I have tried.

After generating an access token with oAuth2, through postman. The settings below:

- Auth URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
- Access Token URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
- ClientID: id
- Client Secret: secret
- Scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.customer

Making a `GET` request to `https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customers/my_customer` with the token and I get a 403 insufficient permissions error back.

Is there something I am missing? I know steps to update the URL require making a get to get the users ID before making the `PUT` request. But I am not able to `GET` anything.

Is there something I am missing? Here is the [URL](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-customers#retrieve_a_customer) to the DOCS if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See [domain rename known issues](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301932). The rename won't work if you are a reseller, purchased your domain via Google Domains or have Chrome licenses.

Comment: Sadly those don't apply for us, we are not a reseller, and the domain is not from Google. So those issues don't really apply to the situation. I will keep digging.